# SQL get LAST record for each ID after some Date

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

I need help creating a SQL statement for retrieving LAST record after some date for each USERID in USER_LOG table.

I forgot to write there are few other columns in this table.

**`TABLE: USER_LOG`**

```
ID  NAME    MODIFY_DATE            MODIFY_TYPE 
55  userA   2013-05-07 15:47:53.0  1
88  userB   2013-05-07 16:00:57.0  1
55  userA   2013-05-08 11:44:10.0  2
88  userB   2013-05-08 15:47:09.0  2 
88  userB   2013-05-08 16:01:41.0  1    
55  userA   2013-05-09 15:11:53.0  0
55  userA   2013-05-09 16:00:57.0  0
55  userA   2013-05-10 09:14:10.0  1
88  userB   2013-05-10 16:01:41.0  2
55  userA   2013-05-10 18:23:03.0  2
55  userA   2013-05-11 09:14:10.0  2
88  userB   2013-05-11 16:01:41.0  1
55  userA   2013-05-13 11:34:07.0  1
55  userA   2013-05-13 15:53:04.0  2
55  userA   2013-05-13 16:13:04.0  1
```

```
Example 1: Get All users they have bean changed after '2013-05-08 00:00:00.0'.
Must return:
```

```
ID  NAME    MODIFY_DATE            MODIFY_TYPE 
55  userA   2013-05-07 15:47:53.0  1
88  userB   2013-05-07 16:00:57.0  1
55  userA   2013-05-08 11:44:10.0  2
88  userB   2013-05-08 15:47:09.0  2 
88  userB   2013-05-08 16:01:41.0  1    
55  userA   2013-05-09 15:11:53.0  0
55  userA   2013-05-09 16:00:57.0  0
55  userA   2013-05-10 09:14:10.0  1
88  userB   2013-05-10 16:01:41.0  2
55  userA   2013-05-10 18:23:03.0  2
55  userA   2013-05-11 09:14:10.0  2
**88    userB   2013-05-11 16:01:41.0  1**  RETURN THIS
55  userA   2013-05-13 11:34:07.0  1
55  userA   2013-05-13 15:53:04.0  2
**55    userA   2013-05-13 16:13:04.0  1**  RETURN THIS
```

```
Example 2: Get All users they have bean changed after '2013-05-12 00:00:00.0'.
Must return:
```

```
ID  NAME    MODIFY_DATE            MODIFY_TYPE 
55  userA   2013-05-07 15:47:53.0  1
88  userB   2013-05-07 16:00:57.0  1
55  userA   2013-05-08 11:44:10.0  2
88  userB   2013-05-08 15:47:09.0  2 
88  userB   2013-05-08 16:01:41.0  1    
55  userA   2013-05-09 15:11:53.0  0
55  userA   2013-05-09 16:00:57.0  0
55  userA   2013-05-10 09:14:10.0  1
88  userB   2013-05-10 16:01:41.0  2
55  userA   2013-05-10 18:23:03.0  2
55  userA   2013-05-11 09:14:10.0  2
88  userB   2013-05-11 16:01:41.0  1  
55  userA   2013-05-13 11:34:07.0  1
55  userA   2013-05-13 15:53:04.0  2
**55    userA   2013-05-13 16:13:04.0  1**  RETURN THIS
```

I found something but I don't know where we put the condition with date after X:

`SELECT u1.* 
    FROM user_log u1 LEFT JOIN user_log u2 
     ON (u1.id = u2.id AND u1.modify_date < u2.modify_date ) 
    WHERE u2.modify_date IS NULL;`

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: sorry to say that but after writting too many text still i can not find the real problem...in your question,,,i must say your question is not clear at all

Answer (score 5):

Well, for these purposes themselves [analytical functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm) were invented.

Here you are:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ID,
  NAME, 
  LAST_VALUE(MODIFY_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY MODIFY_DATE ROWS BETWEEN unbounded preceding and unbounded following) MODIFY_DATE
FROM
  USER_LOG
WHERE
  MODIFY_DATE > :date
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the minimum date after a certain date, grouped by the user data, you should do:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, MIN(MODIFY_DATE) FROM user_log
WHERE MODIFY_DATE > ?
GROUP BY ID, NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query will give you the last record per user after some date X.

```
select * 
  from user_log
 where (id, modify_date) in(
         select id, max(modify_date)
           from user_log
          where modify_date > date '2013-05-12'
          group by id);
```

The sub-query selects all records after 2013-05-12. Out of those records, it selects the last (max) modify_Date for each user. The outer query just returns the whole row.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, NAME, MAX(MODIFY_DATE) FROM user_log
WHERE MODIFY_DATE > datevalue
GROUP BY ID, NAME
```